# Azure Artifact not showing Nuget download count from upstream nuget feed

Tags: azure, nuget, azure-artifacts

I've created an Azure Artifacts Feed including Upstream Sources for NPM and Nuget.
Everything works fine but I noticed that the download count for the Nuget Packages are missing. Is that normal?
When I use nuget.org as source directly I have the download count visible and packages are ordered by download count which is very useful sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Azure Artifacts does not provide download counts to Visual Studio.

Comment: I was hoping that switching to Azure Feeds from a self-hosted feed would finally solve this. Too bad.